# How do I clear validation error messages on a v-form?

Tags: forms, vue.js, validation, modal-dialog

I'm working on a vue.js application. I have a form in a modal that looks like this:

[image]

If I fill out the form and then hit cancel, the modal closes. But then if I open it again, I see validation errors on each control:

[image]

The cancel handler looks like this:

```
    cancelClicked() {
      this.date = null;
      this.time = null;
      this.duration = null;
      this.$emit('cancel');
    }
```

Is there something else I can add just before emitting the 'cancel' event that would reset the validation state of each control so that the next time I open the modal, it doesn't show validation error messages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to open/close this dialog? Are you using v-show? Have you tried it using v-if? Here is some info about the difference between those two [https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-conditional-directives#:~:text=The%20main%20difference%20between%20the,else%2C%20v%2Delse%2Dif](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-conditional-directives#:%7E:text=The%20main%20difference%20between%20the,else%2C%20v%2Delse%2Dif)